# Error con ngswitch y ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic-framework

estoy trabajando con ionic 5 y angular 10,
esoty haciendo un modal y en dicho modal quiero mostrar informacion de productos.

Esoty usando ngswitch para mostrar la informacion pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngSwitchCase' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-col'.
```

He estado buscando que pueda estar mal y encontre que se tenia que importar el 'common modeule' y el 'browser module'. Y ya estan impórtados.
asi es como tengo el modulo del modal

[image: en el module del modal]

Y asi en el app.module
[image: app.module]

Y este es el html que usa el ngSwitch, trabajo con el modal para poder cambiar las pestañas con ion-segment-button

```
        <ion-row [ngSwitch]="segmentModel">
      <ion-col size="12" *ngSwitchCase="'producto'">
        <div class ="product_info">
          <ion-text mode="ios" class="producto_info-desc" class="ion-text-justify">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum quo quod ipsum fugit sit enim delectus incidunt eaque tenetur nemo aliquid ab distinctio temporibus recusandae esse, cupiditate, in optio alias?
          </ion-text>

          <ion-text mode="ios" class="producto_info-desc" class="ion-text-justify">
            <h3>Beneficios</h3>
            <ion-list color="secondary">
              
            </ion-list>
          </ion-text>

          <ion-text mode="ios" class="producto_info-desc" class="ion-text-justify">
            <h3>Modo de acci&oacute;n.</h3>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum quo quod ipsum fugit sit enim delectus incidunt eaque tenetur nemo aliquid ab distinctio temporibus recusandae esse, cupiditate, in optio alias?
          </ion-text>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="12" *ngSwitchCase="'aplicacion'">
        <div class ="product_info">
          <ion-text mode="ios" class="producto_info-desc ion-text-jusify">
            <h3>Caracteristicas</h3>
          </ion-text>
          <ion-text mode="ios" class="producto_info-desc ion-text-jusify">
            <h3></h3>
          </ion-text>
          <ion-text mode="ios" class="producto_info-desc ion-text-jusify">
            <h3>Recomendaciones</h3>
          </ion-text>
          <ion-text mode="ios" class="producto_info-desc ion-text-jusify">
            <h3>Descargas</h3>
          </ion-text>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="12" *ngSwitchDefault>
        <div class="product_info">
          <img src="../../../assets/icon/notfound.svg" alt="no_hay_informacion">
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

¿Como puedo arreglar el problema?
¿Tendre algun error que estoy pasando por alto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, encontre el prroblema. Cuando se va a usar un modal y se vayan a usar las directivas, siempre hay que importar el modalPage en el app.module y agrefarlo al array de declarations.

Un ejemplo y la respuesta a mi pregunta se encuentra en el link siguiente. Por si a alguien le sirva.

[respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62367201/ngfor-doesnt-work-in-modal-angular-ionic)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a englobar row y col en div, y añadir a estos ngSwitch

```
    <div [ngSwitch]="segmentModel">
        <ion-row >
       <div *ngSwitchCase="'producto'">
      <ion-col size="12" >...</ion-col>
      </div>
      </ion-row>
    </div>
```

Espero que te funcione.

Comment: Soy yo de nuevo, agradezco tu comentario, intente lo que mencionaste, y no me hania fuincionado. Habia olvidad importar el modalpage en el app.module, eso era lo que me estaba dando problema.

De todas maneras agradezco tu tiempo

Comment: de nada y gracias a tí